# Getting monthly climatology using xarray in python

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a netCDF file containing daily data for a variable called `var`2001-01-01 to 2010-12-31. I want to compute monthly sum for `var` resulting in a netCDF containing 12 time steps (one for each month of the year). Currently, I am doing this:

```
import xarray as xr
hndl_fl = xr.open_dataset(path_file)

hndl_fl.resample('1MS', dim='time', how='sum')
```

However, this results in a netCDF with monthly sums for each month from 2001 to 2010. How do i get the monthly average for 12 months?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Comments:** I am looking for monthly average for 12 months (for all years from 2001 to 2010). Your solution only computes monthly average for 1 year

My **first** Output start from **2001-01** up to **2010-12**, so all years are coverd.
Do you want to `resample`  these **120** values once more?

---

> How do i get the monthly average for 12 months?

You have to decide what you want:
Average for every Month within a Year, results in 12 Values per Year, up to 120 Values in 10 Years
**or**
Average for 1 Year, results in 10 Values in 10 Years

Using the following `xarray.Dataset`, date_range=10 Years

```
date_range('2001-01-01', '2010-12-31', name='time')
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 3652)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01 2001-01-02 2001-01-03 ...
Data variables:
    data     (time) float64 16.0 18.0 15.0 12.0 23.0 9.0 7.0 18.0 23.0 23.0 ...
```

---

Get the `monthly_avr` for every Month in the `date_range('2001-01-01', '2010-12-31', name='time')`:

```
monthly_avr = ds.resample('1MS', dim='time', how='mean')
```

**Output:**

```
monthly_avr=<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 120)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-03-01 ...
Data variables:
    data     (time) float64 17.42 16.54 19.23 18.37 14.74 17.8 16.45 17.29 ...
```

---

Get the `year_avr` for every Year in the `date_range('2001-01-01', '2010-12-31', name='time')` :

```
year_avr = ds.resample('1AS', dim='time', how='mean')
```

**Output:**

```
year_avr=<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 10)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01 2002-01-01 2003-01-01 ...
Data variables:
    data     (time) float64 17.22 17.13 17.05 17.49 17.38 17.07 16.72 16.47 ...
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - xarray: 0.9.1***

Comment: thanks @stovfl, I am looking for monthly average for 12 months (for all years from 2001 to 2010). Your solution only computes monthly average for 1 year

Answer (score 6):

Either

```
hndl_fl.resample('1MS', dim='time', how='mean')
```

or

```
hndl_fl.groupby('time.month').mean('time')
```

should do the trick, depending on what you want exactly.